# create dictionary from two list with the addition of values with same key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists like below,

```
l1=['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a','a','d','b']
l2=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
```

Now want to create a dictionary from above list such as- key would be unique from l1 and the values from l2 will be added,

so final dictionary would look like,

```
d={'a':24, 'b':20, 'c': 14, 'd':14}
```

I could do this using a for loop but execution time will be more, looking for some python shortcuts to do this most efficiently.

Comment: "short" doesn't mean "fast", though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a','a','d','b']
l2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]    

idx = 0
d = {}
for v in l1:
  d[v] = d.get(v, 0) + l2[idx]
  idx += 1

print d
# {'a': 24, 'b': 20, 'c': 14, 'd': 14}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this with `zip` to iterate parallely:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a','a','d','b']
l2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]

d = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in zip(l1, l2):
    d[k] += v

print(d)
# {'a': 24, 'b': 20, 'c': 14, 'd': 14}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a dict of comprehension:

```
from  more_itertools import unique_everseen
d = {i: sum([l2[x] for x in [y for y,val in enumerate(l1) if val==i]]) for i in  list(unique_everseen(l1))}
```

**Output:**

```
{'a':24, 'b':20, 'c': 14, 'd':14}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `zip()` function. In it we iterate in the 2 lists, then we are creating a new dictionary key `j` which comes from the `l1` and assigning a value to it `i` which comes from the `l2`. If the key from the `l1` is in the dictionary key already, it value will be added as you wanted to.

```
l1=['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a','a','d','b']
l2=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
output = {}
for j, i in zip(l1, l2):
    if j in output.keys():
        output[j] = output[j] + i
    else:
        output[j] = i
print(output)
```